# Iptables drops ACK FIN package in my AP

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I have a Access Point on my Ubuntu machine with iptables. The machine has eth0 and wlan0 that is bridged to form the interface br0.
There should not be any firewall between eth0 and wlan0, I want the traffic to flow freely and unrestricted. If traffic stops at either eth0 or wlan0 the firewall kicks in

So I tried this code in iptables that seams to work.

```
$IPTABLES -N RULE_3
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD  -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in eth0 --physdev-out wlan0  -m state --state NEW  -j RULE_3
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD  -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in wlan0 --physdev-out eth0  -m state --state NEW  -j RULE_3
$IPTABLES -A RULE_3  -j LOG  --log-level info --log-prefix "RULE 3 -- ACCEPT "
$IPTABLES -A RULE_3  -j ACCEPT
```

BUT, for some reasons some package are dropped so I can't f.ex stream youtube on wlan0 devices.
This I found in my log

```
Apr 10 21:32:03 NASHTPC kernel: [273846.062793] RULE 8 -- DENY IN=br0 OUT=br0 PHYSIN=wlan0 PHYSOUT=eth0 MAC=************** SRC=192.168.0.15 DST=17.172.208.47 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=63737 PROTO=TCP SPT=58807 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0  
Apr 10 21:32:03 NASHTPC kernel: [273846.070615] RULE 3 -- ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=br0 PHYSIN=wlan0 PHYSOUT=eth0 MAC=**************** SRC=192.168.0.15 DST=17.172.208.47 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2782 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58808 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Apr 10 21:32:03 NASHTPC kernel: [273846.776553] RULE 8 -- DENY IN=br0 OUT=br0 PHYSIN=wlan0 PHYSOUT=eth0 MAC=************** SRC=192.168.0.15 DST=17.172.208.47 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10631 PROTO=TCP SPT=58807 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
```

It looks like the problem is that the firewall is dropping my ACK/FIN package. Rule 8 is a DENY ALL rule.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Should I change rule 3 to something else to allow the traffic to flow freely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want traffic to flow *unrestricted*, then make it so:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in eth0 --physdev-out wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in wlan0 --physdev-out eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

For more information on the meaning of TCP flags, see: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment)

Answer (score 3):

You are forwarding only `NEW` state, not ACK FIN which are considered ESTABLISHED as everithing after the SYN/ACK packets

Could you try this:

```
$IPTABLES -N RULE_3
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD  -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in eth0 --physdev-out wlan0  -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED  -j RULE_3
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD  -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in wlan0 --physdev-out eth0  -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED  -j RULE_3
$IPTABLES -A RULE_3  -j LOG  --log-level info --log-prefix "RULE 3 -- ACCEPT "
$IPTABLES -A RULE_3  -j ACCEPT
```

[Explanations here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x1414.html)

Comment: This works good, the strange thing is that I already had a rule in the beginning that allows all related and established. But for some reason it was not trigged correctly.
But I choose to remove the "state" part and now everything is allowed.